# php : The term 'php' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: php, windows, git, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to install and setup Laravel 4 through the Git Shell using [this](http://culttt.com/2013/04/29/getting-started-with-laravel-4/) tutorial:

It all seems to be working until I have to run `php artisan key:generate` at which point it gives me the error:

> php : The term 'php' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

I have hunted around and am not sure how to go about setting this up so it recognizes PHP.

Does anyone have any ideas or know of a thorough tutorial to get Laravel 4 setup?

Comment: @AmalMurali I have WAMP installed. Maybe I need to make sure the Laraval installation is within the WWW directory of WAMP?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321639/is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Try adding your `PHP.exe`'s folder to your `System PATH variables`, so PHP can be accessed via terminal.

For example; `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3`

To add new `PATH variable`, follow this:

1. Right click on `My Computer`, select `Properties`
2. Select `Advanced System Settings`
3. In the `System Properties window` click the `Environment Variables button`.
4. Select `System Variables -> PATH` and click Edit.
5. Enter the folder where your `PHP.exe` is located.

If you did this correctly, restart your terminal and type `php --version` to check if it works.

**Note:** Don't forget to seperate paths by using `;` seperator.

Comment: How specifically can I add the `PHP.exe` folder to my PATH variables? I am still new to console programming.

Comment: The error is gone now, but I have another error in it's place, do you know of any good laravel 4 tutorials?

Comment: @Chris What error? You can install Laravel via `composer` if you want, and refer to the documentation in Laravel's website. http://four.laravel.com/#install-laravel

Comment: On the step where it asks me to input `php artisan key:generate` it gives me a "warning failed to open stream: no such file in directory" in the autoload.php in my project. and that becomes a fatal error below it.

Comment: Did you change to the root folder before executing it? `cd C:/wamp/www/laravelFolder`

Comment: I believe so, but am not sure. Is there a way for me to put a screenshot of it up for you to see?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38453/discussion-between-aristona-and-chris)

Answer (score 3):

If Aristona answer doesn't work again check path, you should add variable like this:

`C:\wamp\bin\php\[var]`

Where **`[var]`** is folder where you have **php.exe**, not specific file.

**DON'T** do it like this:

`C:\wamp\bin\php\php.exe`

Answer (score -1):

Try adding your PHP.exe's folder to your System PATH variables, so PHP can be accessed via terminal.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

just install xamp and add path of php folder to system environment variables, will solve all problems

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).