# Error: "is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Whenever I try and run `mycommand.exe` from my Windows `cmd.exe` terminal, I get this error:

> ''mycommand.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file'

**Secondly**

I've also experienced a similar error when I tried to run `C:\Program Files\My-App\Mobile.exe`

> ''C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file'

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This is a very common question seen on Stackoverflow.

The important part here is not the command displayed in the error, but what the actual error tells you instead.

a Quick breakdown on why this error is received.

`cmd.exe` Being a terminal window relies on input and system Environment variables, in order to perform what you request it to do. it does NOT know the location of everything and it also does not know when to distinguish between commands or executable names which are separated by whitespace like <kbd>space</kbd> and <kbd>tab</kbd> or commands with whitespace as switch variables.

> How do I fix this:

**When Actual Command/executable fails**

First we make sure, is the executable **actually** installed? If yes, continue with the rest, if not, install it first.

If you have any executable which you are attempting to run from `cmd.exe` then you need to tell `cmd.exe` where this file is located. There are 2 ways of doing this.

1. specify the full path to the file.

   `"C:\My_Files\mycommand.exe"`
2. Add the location of the file to your environment Variables.

> Goto:
>   ------> Control Panel-> System-> Advanced System Settings->Environment Variables

In the `System Variables` Window, locate `path` and select <kbd>edit</kbd>

Now simply add your path to the end of the string, seperated by a semicolon `;` as:

```
;C:\My_Files\
```

Save the changes and exit. You need to make sure that ANY `cmd.exe` windows you had open are then closed and re-opened to allow it to re-import the environment variables.
Now you should be able to run mycommand.exe from any path, within `cmd.exe` as the environment is aware of the path to it.

**When `C:\Program` or Similar fails**

This is a very simple error. Each string after a white space is seen as a different command in `cmd.exe` terminal, you simply have to enclose the entire path in double quotes in order for `cmd.exe` to see it as a single string, and not separate commands.

So to execute `C:\Program Files\My-App\Mobile.exe` simply run as:

```
"C:\Program Files\My-App\Mobile.exe"
```

Comment: Works! I had to restart my PC for the change to take effect.

Comment: @barto. No need to restart pc. You just need to close cmd.exe and re open for it to read the new environment. But glad this helped. :)

Comment: @Gerhard Thank you very much for the solution, saved my day. Were able to run concurrently npm package by setting up the full path to the scripts. Works like a charm!

Comment: That worked for me.  Stupid double quotes.... but it makes sense. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

When you want to run an executable file from the Command prompt, *(cmd.exe)*, or a batch file, it will:

- Search the current working directory for the executable file.
- Search all locations specified in the `%PATH%` environment variable for the executable file.

If the file isn't found in either of those options you will need to either:

1. Specify the location of your executable.
2. Change the working directory to that which holds the executable.
3. Add the location to `%PATH%` by apending it, *(recommended only with extreme caution)*.

*You can see which locations are specified in `%PATH%` from the Command prompt, `Echo %Path%`.*

Because of your reported error we can assume that `Mobile.exe` is not in the current directory or in a location specified within the `%Path%` variable, so you need to use `1.`, `2.` or `3.`.

**Examples for `1.`**

```bat
C:\directory_path_without_spaces\My-App\Mobile.exe
```

or:

```bat
"C:\directory path with spaces\My-App\Mobile.exe"
```

Alternatively you may try:

```bat
Start C:\directory_path_without_spaces\My-App\Mobile.exe
```

or

```bat
Start "" "C:\directory path with spaces\My-App\Mobile.exe"
```

*Where **`""`** is an empty title, (you can optionally add a string between those doublequotes).*

**Examples for `2.`**

```bat
CD /D C:\directory_path_without_spaces\My-App
Mobile.exe
```

or

```bat
CD /D "C:\directory path with spaces\My-App"
Mobile.exe
```

You could also use the **`/D`** option with `Start` to change the working directory for the executable to be run by the start command

```bat
Start /D C:\directory_path_without_spaces\My-App Mobile.exe
```

or

```bat
Start "" /D "C:\directory path with spaces\My-App" Mobile.exe
```

Comment: Regarding appending to the path - it might be worth mentioning that you can append to your user path, which will then get appended to the system  path. At a lot of sites you can't change system settings anyway without requesting business-justified admin privileges, but you can change your user variables.

Comment: @William, I have no interest in providing advice on modifying the `%PATH%` variable contents. I don't wish to give the impression that changing them is recommended by me, in any way, when other options are available. Gerhard gave some advice on how to change that system variable, perhaps your message was intended for him!

Comment: Perhaps, but I was responding to _recommended only with extreme caution_, since there are two paths deserving two levels of caution.

Comment: @William, I'm not providing the advice, _(I have never needed to change that variables contents, on any version of the OS)_. If you wish to add a new answer, complete with your advice on changing it, please feel free.

Answer (score 2):

when you have this problem

1. search for **Environment variables**

[image]

2. press on **Environment variables**

[image]

3. Under "System varibles" you search for **PATH** and press edit

[image]

4. press on new and add the path of your program and save it
   [image]