# Flutter Android sdk is missing command line tools

Tags: flutter

I added the steps provided by [**docs**](https://flutter.io/setup-windows/).
I also added Android SDK to the environmental variable but it's still remaining an issue.

I also tried [**these steps**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321639/is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat) but it didn't work.

[image]

Also asked on https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19805

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You show the output of `flutter doctor` and at the same time say "`flutter` is not recognized as n internal or external command". If it were not recognized you could not run `flutter doctor`. Why do you not post the output where the error is shown you used as question title. Or is the question actually about the Android SDK? Then please fix the title.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer do you know how to fix this issue i updated my question

Comment: What do you get if your execute `adb --version` in a terminal?

Comment: Perhaps your Android Studio installation is not complete. Were you able to create an Android emulator as explained in https://flutter.io/setup-windows/#install-android-studio ?

Comment: ANDROID_HOME = G:\sdk;
      but Android SDK not found at this location. getting error like tis

Comment: Sorry, don't see the error.

Comment: I tried but it does not work please help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176762/discussion-between-thecodestar-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thank you finally i fixed the error

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For MAC:

```
AndroidStudio -> Preferences -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> 
Android SDK
```

1. choose the SDK Tools Segment
2. Check the Android SDK Command-line tool (latest)

[image]

Comment: After hours looking for it, this was the perfect solution. As simple as it is. Thanks for sharing. ;)

Comment: In the latest version of Android Studio, Preferences can be opened like this too:

More Actions -> SDK Manager

Comment: this one is also working on windows 10. thank you mate

Answer (score 5):

Please try adding

`G:\sdk\tools` and `G:\sdk\platform-tools` to the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: What variable name for this two path in environment?

Comment: You can add them directly without a variable name.

Comment: i have added both sdk\tools and platform-tools to path wich doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

See if it is configured this way in "Project Structure"
[image]

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It is little confusing.
ANDROID_HOME location is not C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
ANDROID_HOME location is     C:\Users\username\AppData\Local

restart command prompt or Power Shell
re-check flutter doctor

Answer (score 0):

I was using Windows 10 and I encounter this issue. I had tried `ANDROID_HOME` to my path but it was not working because I was forget to add tools and build-tools in path variable.
try this Open Edit the system Environment Setting(Search in Windows search).

- Click on Environments Variable -> Create New variable -> Variable
  Name ANDROID_HOME and path your SDK path.
- Double Tap on `PATH` or Edit it Add `platform-tools,build-tools,tools` (All folders are in Your SDK path)

Reopen Terminal and type Flutter Doctor

Done

Answer (score 0):

Open Android studio, then go to appearance and behavior > system settings > android sdk. Then choose SDK Tools instead of the standard SDK Platforms guide. Then choose Android SDK Command-line tools (latest).