# How to run php script in command line interface windows OS

Tags: php, windows, cmd, xampp

I have installed xampp in my windows OS.completed the configuration settings .But i can't run a simple php script from CMD . Is there anything should i do bfore running the script .

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321639/is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure, that php is added to your path variable, so you can run `php -v` in your terminal. You should get the current version of your installed php.

If php was added to your path variable, you can run a php script like `php file.php`

See http://php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.addtopath

Comment: i have already done that..still not worlking. and gettting a response like the following:               'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Then php is not globally available and is not correct in the PATH variable. In case of xampp it would be c:xampp\php

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to go till that file path in command prompt then use command to execute php script,

php file_name.php

Comment: 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Does php installed on your local machine?

Comment: i have installed xampp

Comment: Verify php is installed or not on your local machine using php -v command on command promt. 

If PHP is installed then start `apache` server and then execute PHP script. Also, make sure your script should be inside a `htdocs` folder