# Ionic commands not working in directories outside the local user main folder

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, cmd, ionic4

I am using **ionic v-4**. Previously, ionic was working perfectly fine in all folders. But suddenly it stopped working.

Now, if the directory is in local user folder, it works right. See below in image *(Blue)*

But, if I change the directory to some folder inside the local user folder, then it gives me error: (See below in image) *(Red)*

> ‘ionic’ is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

[image: Screen from cmd showing error]

I tried to follow up on some previous questions from different forums and uninstalled node, ionic and cordova. Then I cleared cache and then clean installed everything again using

```
npm install -g ionic
```

but still it gives me the same error.

I also tried to change the environment variables to the correct path of npm but no change.
Moreover, I tried using command prompt as an administrator too but still same error.

If anyone can suggest me some solution to fix this, I’d be very grateful because I have an ionic exam coming and I need to practice haha :D

PS. My account is the admin account so run as administrator doesn’t really matter.

**Edit 1:** I already tried everything (changing the path from environment variables) that's mentioned in the answer of duplicate question link but sadly, it didn't work for me. See Below

[image: environment variables]

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321639/is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resetting my pc to default settings** worked for me. Probably there was some problem in registry or environment variables path which I couldn't figure out but now it's solved.