# Installing Python Python 3.7 + Tensorflow 2.0 + Jupyter Notebook 2020 and facing Problems

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am a beginner in python and started to install Python via the following tutorial:
[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bgK-Qy7qLGE).

I have downloaded the **python3.7.5**. After installing that, I have moved to command prompt for further **tensor flow 2.0** installation. I used the following commands:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

then

```
 pip install jupyter
```

then

```
jupyter-notebook.exe
```

After this command, I got the error

```
C:\Users\Nafee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts>jupyter-notebook.exe
'jupyter-notebook.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Please help me to get out this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321639/is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run

```
jupyter notebook
```

Not jupyter-notebook.exe

Comment: Actually jupyter was not installed correctly. I installed again using `pip install jupyter` .  Then used your mentioned command. Now it's working. Thank you.