# Jenkins launching app(mongod) through batch is closing it instantly

Tags: mongodb, batch-file, jenkins

did somebody encounter this issue?
I am running jenkins job executing one batch file...this batch file has a set of commands:

1. start mongod.exe (I've got localhost db set up on the node)
2. do some command to run .js updating database, e.g. "mongo C:/xxx.js"
   Now when I run this batch file manually on my PC/on my Jenkins node manually, everything's working fine.
   However once trying to run it through Jenkins, it acts like starting of mongod passed, and then when calling mongo C:/xxx.js, I'm getting

```
 'mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
```

EDIT: I have mongod on my PATH env variable..

I even added timeout for few seconds between mongod start and mongo command, however it did not help.
I tried to investigate closely -> I've run Jenkins job, and then, while timeout was being processed, I tried to access localhost db on node - worked fine for few seconds, then it was not accessible - mongod has stopped.

Comment: I suggest you have a [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321639/is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat)

Comment: I still doubt that your path is correct, after your edit. I suggest you prove it is by using the `where` command?