# Windows Command prompt - nnictl command not recognized

Tags: python

I have tried installing nni packages in windows command prompt,it installed successfully.but when i tried to command,

**"nnictl create --config nni\example/trails\mnist-pytorch\config_windows.yml"**

in windows command prompt.it says,

**'nnictl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.**

how can i fix this error?

Comment: please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321639/is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat if this solves the problem. Windows require applications to be added to the `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved! I just installed anaconda3 and tried installing nni packages in it.And also it recognized **'nnictl'** command in anaconda3 prompt automatically by setting path variables.Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

On my pc the nni package was already installed through Anaconda, but I've got the same error. Instead of modifying the PATH variable I've written a batch script like:

```
set root=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Anaconda3
call %root%\Scripts\activate.bat %root%
call C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts\nnictl create --config config_windows.yml
pause
```