# converting default.gpj file to makefile

Tags: windows, makefile, greenhills

please tell me steps to convert default.gpj file to a makefile.

I created a helloworld C example,compiled in Greenhills(Multi IDE),after compiling getting a default.gpj file,trying to convert this one into a makefile.

In command prompt using the below command

"gpjmodify default.gpj -generate_makefile"

but getting a error message "gpjmodify is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file".

could any one please tell me how to convert .gpj file to makefile.

Regards,
Asha.S.D

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321639/is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat)

Comment: thank you for the replay,I gone through the link,I understood bit more,normally this error shows when make.exe is not installed,after installing make.exe it will solve that issue. but in ghs case their is  many program utilities called gstack,gfile,gpjmodify etc...their is option to enable and disable this utilities,in my system "gpjmodify" utility is not enabled so could any one tell me how to enable the "gpjmodify" utility.

Comment: Hi guys..waiting for your replies,help me regarding this.