# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdfplumber'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, pdfplumber

I would like to import `pdfplumber` and tried

```
import pdfplumber
```

and caught error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-b3d6737fd8e1> in <module>
----> 1 import pdfplumber

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdfplumber'
```

Tried to install using `pip3 install pdfplumber` and it returned:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pdfplumber in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (0.5.26)
Requirement already satisfied: pdfminer.six==20200517 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from pdfplumber) (20200517)
Requirement already satisfied: Wand in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from pdfplumber) (0.6.5)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow>=7.0.0 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from pdfplumber) (7.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sortedcontainers in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from pdfminer.six==20200517->pdfplumber) (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet in c:\users\harper.guo\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from pdfminer.six==20200517->pdfplumber) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pycryptodome in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from pdfminer.six==20200517->pdfplumber) (3.10.1)
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.3.3; however, version 21.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\python38\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

But Command Prompt showed that I already have installed the module?

```
>>> pdfplumber
<module 'pdfplumber' from 'C:\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages\\pdfplumber\\__init__.py'>
```

But `import pdfplumber` returned the same erro. How to import `pdfplumber`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it has to do with the Python version that I used.

In the top right hand corner of VS Code it shows that my Python version was Python 3

[image]

Clicking on it and changing it to Python 3.8.5 and the code worked. This was done after I restarted VS Code and my laptop, and created new path.

[image]

Creating a new path in Environment Variables following these resources:

[1. 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23709194/11901732)

[2. 2020 How to Fix "No Module Named..." Error in Python | Python Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I9st-DgQoWc)

[3. Python Virtual Environments: A Primer](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/#:%7E:text=Remove%20ads-,What%20Is%20a%20Virtual%20Environment%3F,dependencies%20every%20other%20project%20has.)

[4. '' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48321640/11901732)