# 'cassandra' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: cassandra

I have downloaded Cassandra 4 and trying to run it by executing 'cassandra -f' in its bin directory. I have set CASSANDRA_HOME env variable to root folder of the installation. But I get error as:

> ```
> 'cassandra' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> ```

What is the issue here? I am running command in bin folder, so it should be able to detect it and run. I even added ../bin to PATH variable, but still same issue. I am on Windows 10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321639/is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat)

Comment: I have already done what is suggested in that answer. I am running command inside bin folder of the installation, and have added it to PATH var too. But nothing works.

Comment: running inside `bin` folder doesn't help because it's not in PATH. Run `./cassandra` from inside of it