# julia : The term 'julia' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if

Tags: julia

I tried to run the command `julia "d:\juliya\programming\hello.jl"`; however it throws this error:

```
julia : The term 'julia' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script 
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ julia "d:\juliya\programming\hello.jl"
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (julia:String) [], CommandNotFoundExceptio
   n
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321639/is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat)

Comment: From where are you executing that command?