# Issue related to while running jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter

```
pip install mysqlclient pymysql
```

After running the above command it is showing the following error message:

> 'C:\Users\Aparna' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321639/error-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-o ?

Comment: Have you tried running in a cell inside your notebook, `%pip install mysqlclient pymysql`?