# pip install within ArcPro 2.9.1 produces 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command error, how can I change the install dir?

Tags: python, arcgis

I am attempting to install xlsxwriter module in my ArcPro 2.9.1. I receive an error that the directory is not recognized as an internal or external commmand.

```
pip install xlsxwriter
"'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
```

This seems it is happening due to the space in 'Program files' but I am unsure of how to change the directory for pip install.

I would change the install directory to "C:\Program Files..." within quotes to prevent this error.

Please let me know how to go about changing the install directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you feel like it's issue with windows path. If you want alternate solution until you fix path issue then you can install modules like this.Try this let me know if it works.

```
import os
os.system("pip install xlsxwriter")
```

Comment: That brought up cmd and it did seem to install , but the output in the arcpro notebook is "0". I then tried '''import xlsxwriter''' and recieved the error "No module named 'xlsxwriter', so I don't believe it did install.

Comment: ohh...I'm using Python IDLE. In my just to I've uninstalled & installed again using `os.system`. It worked in case...Let me analyze once again

Comment: @pabstack are u using any environmnet in conda?

Comment: I'm new to this, but no I don't believe I am using conda.

Comment: I think ArcGIS Notebooks are built on top of the Jupyter Notebook,?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249634/discussion-between-pabstack-and-bhargav).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48321640/15358800 look at this\

Comment: It looks like the installation worked, but there is some issue with the importing. New problem, but thanks for answering the first one.

Comment: Looks like using sys.path.linsert(0, 'mypath/') worked for fixing the importing issue. Thanks again!