# he term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

how can i solve this?
iam trying run this command in vs code terminal but its keep giving this eror

```
PS C:\Users\Hesam\Desktop\cloud> python src/stats.py --chat_json C:\Users\Hesam\Desktop\chat ex\result.json --output_dir C:\Users\Hesam\Desktop\res.png
python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name
```

i am just want to run this project

Comment: Have you installed Python? Is it on your PATH?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: "is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321639/error-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-o)

Comment: i think i've did. how can i ckeck that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the very first in the place you typed "python" type py. I mean type py instead of python. I hope it will work

py src/stats.py --chat_json C:\Users\Hesam\Desktop\chat ex\result.json --output_dir C:\Users\Hesam\Desktop\res.png

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having problems, try this:

1. Searching for and click on `Edit the system environment variables` in the Windows search bar
2. Click on `Environment variables` in the bottom right corner
3. Scroll down under `User variables for {YOUR_USERNAME}` and double-click on `Path`
4. On the right click `New` and enter in the path to Python on your computer (it should look something like this: `C:\Users\{USERNAME}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python{VERSION}\`) (If you've already done this, there should be a entry with the directory to Python already)
5. Click `OK` on all opened windows and `Apply` if allowed
6. Restart your computer

If you need help finding your python directory, here is an article: https://datatofish.com/locate-python-windows/

Hope this helps!