# Create a python script to compile and run a Fortran program

Tags: python, subprocess, gfortran

I want to create a Python script to run many Fortran files "at once". The main reason for this is that I've done many Fortran numerical simulations, so I want to speed up to get the process of running all of the Fortran Files with one click (in general, the numerical solutions will be altered according to some input archive, thus, it is useful to modify the input and run the python scripts, which will compile and execute the Fortran programs, and by the way, there are other scripts to plot and obtain linear regression).
The code is as follows:

```
# ------ Run the compiler (ucnum8.f) and run the .exe (ucnum8.exe) by a script ---------
# All other modules were imported at the beginning of the code, which I didn't place here
# Import modules
import subprocess, os

# sub_subdir_baixa is a list of directories
for e in sub_subdir_baixa:
    print(f'Compiling and running {e}...')
    # Change the directory to the specified subdirectory
    os.chdir(e)

    # Compilation command
    compile_command = f'gfortran ucnum8.f -o ucnum8'
    subprocess.run(compile_command, shell=True)

    # Execute the command
    execute_command = './ucnum8.exe'
    subprocess.run(execute_command, shell=True)

    os.chdir('..')
```

The Error reads: '.'  is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
The Fortran compilation works fine without the script

I've tried to put a cd at the variable compile_command, so:

compile_command = f'cd {path} gfortran ucnum8.f -o ucnum8'
taking out the os.chdir

Instead of:
compile_command = f'gfortran ucnum8.f -o ucnum8'
with the os.chdir function.

At this scenerial, the Error indicates that couldn't find the Fortran file. In this case, I undestood since the {path} were not read properly for some reason. Even though the variable path were properly created using the module os, replacing the backslashes, because of my Windows system, the path inserted in the variable compile_command seems to have been broken into parents and sons directories.

I've also used the module glob to find the files I wanted. However, the same type of error, if I'm not wrong, happened. So I prefer to maintain my usual way to access folders with the os module

I've seen this topic [Error: "is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321639/error-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-o)

And it makes sense for me, however I'm not really in depth of how this all works. Do you have any suggestion? Making the adjustments in the topic above is needed? I appreciate your time to help me

Comment: Does `compile_command` create `exe` files?

Comment: You are asking the compiler to create `ucnum8`, not `ucnum8.exe`. Are you sure that on MS Windows the `.exe` is added for you somehow?

Comment: You are on Windows here.  The command shell doesn't understand forward slashes in paths, so `"./ucnum8.exe"` is seen as running the command "dot" with a switch.  Just change that to `"ucnum8.exe"`.  You don't need the dot-slash on Windows.

Comment: Yeah, the compile_command creates exe files, but doesn't execute them, so I do not get the output file (.OUT)  The Fortran language starts with program (name of the program), so in my case (name of the program) = ucnum8. That's why I've added ucnum8 also. That's the way we compile Fortran codes. I will try to change from "./ucnum8.exe" to "ucnum8.exe", although I'm not sure if it's the issue bcuz why I execute a Fortran program (.exe program) i just put it as "./ucnum8.exe" and powershell or cmd and it works fine.

Comment: bcuz when I execute**

Comment: Hey, right now I've applied the suggestion from @TimRoberts, and it worked great. Thx for all of u

Comment: And on a side note, @VladimirFГероямслава, yes, Windows adds the extension automatically.  The environment variable PATHEXT gives the list of extensions it will try in that case.  EXE, COM, BAT, PS1, and some others are on the list.  I commonly add .PY and .PYW.

Comment: `./something.exe` (with forward slash) works in PowerShell but not in cmd. In cmd the forward slash is used in things like `dir /s`. However, `.\something.exe` (with backslash) does work in cmd.