# How to fix extension configuration error in visual studio code?

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code

I have a project on a hosted server. I downloaded the whole Laravel folder and launched the website in visual studio code using IIS express. I successfully ran command line code to enable show directory listing for the site however when I try to access the index.php file I get an error "The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. It is possible that a handler mapping is missing."

I already downloaded PHP to my computer and added "php.validate.executablePath": "c:/php/php.exe" to the settings.json file. Do you know what else I need to do to view the site in localhost?

Comment: I found the fix here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124930/php-the-term-php-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet-function-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows in the control panel go to Advanced System Settings
In the System Properties window click the Environment Variables button.
Select System Variables -> PATH and click new.
Enter the folder where your PHP.exe is located.

Then in visual studio code open the commandline and enter php artisan serve to run the site in the browser.