# Why I am getting error when I was trying to open https://localhost:8000

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, terminal, localhost

when I need to open localhost site https://localhost:8000 for my PHP code.
So I wrote this line in my VS code terminal

php -S localhost:8000

But I am getting error.

*copied and pasted*

```
php : The term 'php' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ php -S localhost:8000
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (php:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at [php : The term 'php' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124930/php-the-term-php-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet-function-script)

Comment: I configured XAMPP.. other things are fine

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I really grateful to you @Dev Utkarsh.. take love

Comment: Great to know it worked out! Welcome to Stackoverflow :)